# forbiden | You don't have permission to access /pub/static

Tags: magento-2.1, access

I have this error:

```
"Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/templates/collection.html on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."
```

I run thoses commands on root:

```
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} \;
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} \;
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

then those on bin:

```
php magento setup:upgrade
php magento setup:di:compile
php magento setup:static-content:deploy
php magento cache:clean
```

Everything is ok. The issue that after few minutes I have the same error message
"Forbiden..."

Comment: Try : `sudo chown www-data:www-data pub/* -R`

Comment: Any solutions, please?

Answer (score -1):

probably you had deleted folders and files inside pub/static so you are getting permission issue use following command `chmod -R 775 pub/static/` and also please check which user you are using.